# How to implement override method for Android native abstract class in Nativescript?

Tags: android, overriding, bluetooth-lowenergy, nativescript

As a NativeScript noob, I am playing around with NativeScript in general and Bluetooth Classic/Bluetooth LE in special, currently using the native Android Bluetooth API.
I'm testing on BT LE capable devices with Android 5.0.2 and Cyanogenmod 13.1 (i.e. Android 5.1). NativeScript version is 1.5.2.

In my playground app I've got basic Bluetooth Classic functionalities working but I'm stuck when it comes to the callback for BluetoothLE scanning (using the Android 5.0+ BTLE-API). My code looks like this:

```
btAdapter = android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if(null !== btAdapter && btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    btLeScanner = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    btLeScanner.startScan(new android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback({
        onScanResult: function(callbackType, result) {
            console.log("BT LE scan result");
        }
    }));
}
```

To what I understand right now from the [NativeScript documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/generator/extend-class-interface) and the specification of Androids abstract [ScanCallback class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback.html), this should be the correct way of implementing the callback.

Excerpt from platforms/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true" />
```

When the code is executed, I get the following error: "Cannot convert JavaScript object with id xxxxxxxx at index 0", referencing to "new android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback ..."

So, short question: what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you aren't extending the abstract [ScanCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback.html) class. Instead, you are using the syntax for implementing an interface ([see {N} docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/generator/extend-class-interface#interfaces) on implementing an interface). To extend a class you should call *extend()* on the ScanCallback class (see [the {N} documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/generator/extend-class-interface#classes) on extending classes).

In your case, you should first extend the android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback and then create a new instance of your derived class, which will inherit from android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback.

```
// Extend the android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback class.
var MyScanCallback = android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback.extend({
    onScanResult: function(callbackType, result) {
        console.log('BT LE scan result');
    }
});
btAdapter = android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (null !== btAdapter && btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    btLeScanner = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    // Now call btLeScanner.startScan and create an instance of our derived 
    // callback class named MyScanCallback.
    btLeScanner.startScan(new MyScanCallback());
}
```

I haven't tested the code, but off the top of my head this is the way you should extend native android classes.